# Chrome packaged apps Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined at urlIsSameOrigin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-app

I am getting the following error in  **"Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
    at urlIsSameOrigin"**

Following is the message in the console.

```
at chrome-extension://ekcelkaofohapfaiajpiilcaelhfnkmj/angular/angular.min.js:9984:21
at chrome-extension://ekcelkaofohapfaiajpiilcaelhfnkmj/angular/angular.min.js:17691:17
at Scope.$eval (chrome-extension://ekcelkaofohapfaiajpiilcaelhfnkmj/angular/angular.min.js:11697:28)
at Scope.$apply (chrome-extension://ekcelkaofohapfaiajpiilcaelhfnkmj/angular/angular.min.js:11797:23)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://ekcelkaofohapfaiajpiilcaelhfnkmj/angular/angular.min.js:17690:21)
at HTMLFormElement.x.event.dispatch (chrome-extension://ekcelkaofohapfaiajpiilcaelhfnkmj/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5:10006)
at HTMLFormElement.y.handle (chrome-extension://ekcelkaofohapfaiajpiilcaelhfnkmj/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5:6789)
```

I am new to chrome apps and angular. This is the code which i am trying

```
    var post = {
        email : $scope.login.email,
        pass : $scope.login.password
    };

    var config = {
        params : {
            login_attempt : loginAttempts
        }
    };

    $http('POST', 'facebook.com/login.php', post, function(status, response) {
        console.log('Success');
    }, function(status, response) {
        console.log('Error');
    });
```

It is a simple http post.

Comment: It's hard to understand your question without the code to the app. What's the manifest? What's the background page? In which context is this code snippet running?

Comment: Did you try with `http://facebook.com/login.php`? Or `https://...` From `angular.js` code: function `urlResolve()` expect some protocol to be there.

Comment: The above code is called in a controller.js file and not in the background.js. The manifest has nothing special except the permissions (check the first answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the simple ajax call working for sending out the request

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('email', $scope.login.email);
data.append('pass', $scope.login.password);


var url = 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
// xhr.setRequestHeader('origin', 'https://facebook.com');
// xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onload = function() {
    var state;
    switch(this.readyState) {
        case 0:
            state = 'request not initialized';
            break;
        case 1:
            state = 'server connection established';
            break;
        case 2:
            state = 'request received';
            break;
        case 3:
            state = 'processing request';
            break;
        case 4:
            state = 'request finished and response is ready';
            break;
    }
    state += ' ';
    state += xhr.status;
    console.log(state);
    $('.result').html(state);
};
xhr.send(data);
```

I am getting a response now from facebook.com as 301 followed by a invalid_login page.

FYI the manifest.json has the following property

```
"permissions": ["http://*.facebook.com/*", "https://*.facebook.com/*"],
```